# view form for Array attributes of mongomapper model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongomapper

I'm bumbling my way around the view-layer and docs in rails and I was wondering if anyone has any tips on what is the best way to set up the Product form so users can select multiple area_codes to populate the permitted_area_codes array in the Product model (the the area code values are being cached in the array rather than the ids)

```
class AreaCode
     include MongoMapper::Document

      key :area_code_value, String, :required => true, :unique => true
end

class Product
    include MongoMapper::Document
    key :name, String, :required => true
    key :permitted_area_codes, Array
end
```

My pretty hopeless attempt looks like this at the moment (below). It doesn't permit multiple options being selected but a single selection seems to be fine. I found  the multiple => true etc in some pretty old blogs and they don't seem to have any effect. Ideally I would like the user to be able to make selections using a series of checkboxes. Maybe there just aren't direct form builder options to do this?

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
   <%= render "shared/error_messages", :target => @product %>
     <div class="field">
       <%= f.label :name %><br />
       <%= f.text_field :name %>
     </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label "Available in areas: " %><br />
      <%= f.select :permitted_area_codes,    options_from_collection_for_select(AreaCode.all, :area_code_value, :area_code_value), :multiple => true, :size => AreaCode.count %>
   </div>

    <div class="actions">
       <%= f.submit %>
     </div>
 <% end %>
```

I have resolved the multiple select issue as I have outlined in the comment.

Comment: My mistake was to `{multiple => true, :size => AreaCode.count}` into the rails options rather than the html options. I should have had something like this 
    `<%= f.select :permitted_area_codes,    options_from_collection_for_select(AreaCode.all, :area_code_value, :area_code_value), { :prompt => "Please select"}, { :multiple => true, :size => SpeciesType.count } %>`

Comment: or slightly neater ` <%= f.collection_select :permitted_area_codes, AreaCode.all, :area_code_value, :area_code_value,{ :prompt => "Please select"}, { :multiple => true, :size => AreaCode.count } %>`